# AngularJS display login page on full screen

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have my angularjs app that has a topbar navigation, a left sidebar navigation and the rest is for the content (using `data-ng-view` I get different views).

My question is, if I have a view called login and a route that redirects me to the login page, how can I show that view actually in the full screen of the page?

Now if I navigate to http://applicationurl.com/#/login the view is like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I cannot figure it out how can I achieve this in AngularJS?

The html is something like this:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

   <header>...</header> // top navigation bar

   <div id="container">

        <nav>...</nav>  //left bar navigation

        <div id="content">

             <div id="wrap" data-ng-view="">
                         // here are loaded all the views ...
             </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be to move your header/footer/sidebar into Angular Views and then use the [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to build the pages with multiple named views where needed.

Comment: Does this solves the problem that angularjs allows only one data-ng-view directive in the app?

Comment: @DavidDury - Read the 'Nested Views' and 'Multiple & Named Views` sections of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to modify your code, it is not possible to achieve what you want to accomplish.  By virtue of your login page being rendered by ng-view, it will be inserted within that tag on the page.  You could hide the header and navbar with ng-hide set on some scope variable that would be set when the login page was rendered, and then the variable could be reset upon successful login/traversal to another page.  This is a bit hacky, and is certainly not ideal, but is a quick and dirty fix.  If you want to learn and do it correctly, Justin's suggestion is a great place to start.